# DataTables 1.9.4 fnAdjustColumnSizing - where to place the resize

Tags: java, jquery, html, datatables

I'm using DataTables 1.9.4, specifically `fnAdjustCiolumnSizing`.

I've checked the other posts that I've seen on this, but they all have one thing in common, they don't explain where they put this function in their code. In terms of Reddit - please explain it like I'm 5!

I have my jquery.datatables.js file and another with the attributes I want to call for my table. However, I am not sure where to place the following:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
});
```

Do I need to declare anything else within HTML etc?

I am new to Java and jQuery so any help would be welcome.

Comment: Try reading http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp, but on your question - in <script> tags!

Comment: @Minister would I put the code at the top in the page header or just under the </table>?

Comment: Try inserting before </head>...

Comment: Apologies for sounding particularly stupid with this problem, now have it fixed thanks very much!

Comment: Great! :-) Please take more time when writing your future questions and make them as clear as possible to receive positive answers! :-)

Comment: Now that you've solved your problem, you might want to visit the JED website.  JED was designed to work with DataTables on the Java platform which is what I see you're working on. http://jed-datatables.ca/jed/

Answer (score 0):

You should have it after your datatable init code - otherwise it might get called before the table is initialized, resulting in an error.

Normally you'll initialize the datatable from a $(document).ready function, to ensure everything needed has been loaded. Set up the window resize handler after that.